# How do I view my current user/password in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, password

I'm currently installing Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

I installed Bash and set up the user on normally. Everything worked fine, but I didn't want to keep doing `sudo` with every command. I uninstalled then reinstalled 'Bash on Ubuntu on Wwindows' with

```
lxrun /install /y
```

It saved the username, but not the previous password. I'm trying to view the current password for the user that I am using.

How do I view the password to my user in Bash?

Comment: I don't know if you can view the password. You can run `sudo passwd yourusername` to change it. If you don't have sudo access, you can run as root with `lxrun /setdefaultuser root`

Comment: You can't view your password, but why would you want to do that? What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you want to configure sudo not to ask for a password, that's a different matter, it doesn't require storing any password anywhere, you just configure it not to ask for the password. If that's something specific to Linux-on-Windows then it's probably something similar but I wouldn't know.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `sudo` with every command?

Answer (score 38):

You can't actually, your password is hashed and is only a 1-way decoded.

To summarize it, just imagine each time you try to login, it will do something like

```
if hash('password') == currentHash;
do grantAccess();
```

and each time you save a password, will do

```
hashedPass = hash('password');
writeOnShadowFile('hashedPass')
```

This is by security standards of hashing avoid storing a real password, but instead storing the result of a function, and evaluating it on that way. Hashing functions are intended to do lot of the original value conversion with data loss, and due the data loss it will make almost impossible to know your original password.

You can easily change your password with `usermod -p <password> <user>`, or just `passwd <user>`.

Answer (score 13):

It's not possible to see what the OS user passwords are. The passwords are stored in a [hashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) form. You can only check if you know one right. Not only would that be a security threat, but also passwords should be changed regularly. And the new one shouldn't be too similar to the old one. But in home environment (as opposed to a professional one) you shouldn't be bothered with this by your command line.

Answer (score 9):

You can't! For good reasons. It would be a huge security flaw.
You can change the password with the `passwd` command (see `man passwd`).

If you are root you can change passwords for all users.